# Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.MinHeight'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to add a CommandBar on my Windows Phone 8.1 app, using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2. Here is the XAML code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="appbarbutton"/>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The `<CommandBar>...</CommandBar>` tags have the blue squiggly lines with the following error:

> Error  1   The text associated with this error code could not be found.
>
> Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.MinHeight'. [Line: 6 Position: 9]

How can I resolve this error? I'm relatively new to Windows Phone and C#, having started only last week. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: setting `MinHeight` may not be the actual issue. could you post some more details about the error eg. whole xaml, stack trace etc? or perhaps a working sample which can reproduce the same.

Comment: I've updated the xaml and removed `MinHeight`, and I get the same error. I just created a Blank Windows Phone App (Visual C#). Then on MainPage.xaml, Document Outline > BottomAppBar -> Add Commandbar. Same error as above...

Comment: Does error still persist if you remove the CommandBar? check the Mainpage.g.cs for Line: 6 Position: 9 and see if there is something interesting (usually somewhere in obj folder). As I do not windows phone env now so I may only able to hint you.

Comment: I've followed the steps: Blank App, DocumentOutline, AddCommandBar - seems to work. Maybe there is other problem in your code? Maybe try to clean your solution/restart VS.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. @pushpraj If I remove the `Page.BottomAppBar` block the error goes away. There doesn't seem to be anything worthwhile on the `Mainpage.g.cs` file. @Romasz That's the same steps I followed. My solution is clean apart from the CommandBar block. Also, This error seems to occur no matter which Windows Phone App template I select (non-Silverlight). I guess it's an issue with my VS2013 installation?

Comment: @AntonioPared Your description of the App is quite sufficient (blank app with commandbar), but can you [try this project](http://1drv.ms/1yARpUX)? - it works fine in my case both on emulator and device. Strange situation.

Comment: @Romasz, when I installed Update 3 RC this issue went away, and I was able to open you example app, as well as my own app without any errors. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

For those experiencing the same problem Visual Studio Express 2013 Update 2, this error is resolved by updating Visual Studio 2013 to Update 3 RC.

Here's the [download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=43398)