# Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.Height'

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I am having the same issue mentioned here: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816994/failed-to-assign-to-property-windows-ui-xaml-frameworkelement-minheight)

The issue is that everything runs smoothly. my windows phone App is working fine however, the command bar button is showing green squiggly lines under the first `appBarButton` and the error messages are:

> The text associated with this error code could not be found.
>
> Failed to assign to property
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.Height'. [Line: 145 Position: -39]

searched in every xaml and cs page for line 145 and failed to find the reason.

and when ever I delete an `appBarButton` the next `AppBarButton` will generate the same error.

So I tried the following solutions:

- The link above SO question suggested that update 3 VS2013 will resolve it. But I am already using VS2013 Update 3.
- Some website support [Telerik] forum suggested that you delete the obj and bin folder and rebuild. But again that didn't help.

I would appreciate any help in this regard

Comment: Did you have find a solution to this problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: Sorry i didnt find the cause fir such error, but i suspect that it is IDE issue not a developer mistake. I ended up by removing the commandbar from each page and created a basePage that contains appBarButtons created by the code not the xaml, then every page in my solution will inherit that page. I hope that help you

Comment: Well, I've tried building it anyway, and it seems to be fine now.